# I cannot calculate mean and sd in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

My problem is that I don't understand why I cannot calculate mean and sd of a variable total.

Steps that I have done:

1. I filtered the dataset in order to see data only from day 1 to 7.
2. I have summarised values from the variable "x" and created a new variable "Total"

I have a dataset:

```
name  day  x  
ab    1    3    
cd    3    5
fg    7    2
ll    3    1
kk    9    0
```

My code:

```
df_changed <- df%>%
dplyr::group_by(`name`, `day` )%>%
dplyr::filter(`day`>= 1, `day`<= 7) %>%
dplyr::summarise(Total=sum(x, na.rm = TRUE))%>%
dplyr::summarise(mean = mean(Total), sd = sd(Total)) %>%
view(df_changed)
```

Comment: After grouping, each group has only 1 row, i.e. one value, standard deviation of a single value is NA, or you don't calculate SD of a single value.

Comment: Adding to Karthik's comment: to solve this and calculate mean and SD over all rows you might want to include `ungroup()` after your first  `summarise()`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you may want to calculate mean and SD of `x` instead of `Total` as stated.  Try this code

```
library(tidyverse)

df_changed <- df%>%
dplyr::group_by(`name`, `day` )%>%
dplyr::filter(`day`>= 1, `day`<= 7) %>%
dplyr::summarise(Total=sum(x, na.rm = TRUE), 
                 mean = mean(x, na.rm = T), 
                 sd = sd(x, na.rm =T))
```